# Pulling a video id from YouTube embed code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, preg-match

I am trying to port over a PHP `preg_match` expression to pull a video ID from YouTube embed code in Javascript. I currently have this in PHP:

```
$pattern = '%(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})[a-zA-Z0-9\<\>\"]%x';
$result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
```

This works and returns me a video id. I have tried using the following in order to get it to work in Javascript:

```
var reg = /(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})/g;
var matches = uploadVideoEmbedCode.match(reg);
```

The test data I am using is:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1NMUDb3Ewhs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I try and use the above regular expression in javascript I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

You help as ever would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't you think you should give credit to the answer owner on your blog? http://www.neilyoungcv.com/blog/code-share/retrieving-youtube-video-id-from-embed-code-using-php-and-javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` slashes in your regex as they are the delimiter. Use `\/` whenever you want to match a literal `/`:

```
var reg = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})/g;
```

Another option would be using `new RegExp('...', 'g')` instead of `/.../g` - but then you need to escape each backslash which would be even more annoying:

```
var reg = new RegExp('(?:https?://)?(?:www\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be/|youtube\\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\\?v=))([\\w-]{10,12})', 'g');
```

To get the ID eventually, use `var id = reg.exec(yourString)[1]`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have done the trick and is now working ok with the following code: var reg = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})/g; However it does not return the video id but the full url whereas PHP returns Array ( [0] => http://www.youtube.com/embed/mHhieh0q_-A" [1] => mHhieh0q_-A )

Comment: See my update on how to properly execute the regex to get the matches.

Comment: Obviously I need to brush up on my reg ex for Javascript :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the forward slashes in your regular expression: `\/`.